# Convert screen coordinates to game coordinates

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm using handling inputs from user by using `EventListenerMouse` on desktop, and `EventListenerTouchOneByOne` for mobile. They work great.

The coordinates recorded are relative to the screen coordinates. The documentation [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Coordinate_System#How-to-convert-coordinates) describes how to convert them into in game coordinates.

However, it does not seem to care about the screen scaling. For example, if I had set the design resolution as the following in `AppDelegate`:

```
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(1280, 720, ResolutionPolicy::FIXED_WIDTH);
```

And let's say, at run-time, the game is run on device with a different resolution:

```
if(!glview)
{
    glview = GLView::createWithRect("My Game", Rect(0, 0, 800, 450));
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}
```

Now, the touch/mouse coordinates captured would be relative to the screen (800x450). How do I convert them into the game coordinates (1280x720)? Does cocos2d-x support ray picking etc?

**Edit:** for now, this is what I'm doing to get around it.

```
point = convertToNodeSpace(point);
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto view = director->getOpenGLView();
point.x /= view->getScaleX();
point.y /= view->getScaleY();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your AppDelegate.cpp, just add this code:

glview->setDesignResolutionSize(1280,720,ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL);

Now the device resolution doesn't matter. The director will set the above resolution for all the devices.

Comment: Sorry, `SHOW_ALL` is not what I want. I need `FIXED_WIDTH`.